# A demo page for latest WebSocket protocol

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, websocket

I've been searching all over the web for simple page that demos WebSocket. But all the examples I find seem to support an older protocol, failing to work in Firefox 6 and Chrome 14.

For example: http://html5demos.com/web-socket

I'd just like to see some workable demo somewhere, so I could make sure that it's my code that's failing not the browser-implementation of web socket.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 14 with an internal WebSocket application and it works fine. Although you're not explicitly asking it, perhaps you can post some details of your code so that it can be fixed.

Comment: Actually my main problem now is Firefox. I should in theory be able to use the same JavaScript code in Firefox, simply replacing WebSocket with MozWebSocket, but it doesn't seem to work. It might be that my server is buggy, or the MozWebSocket implementation is.

Comment: Yes. The javascript in the page suggested by Cameron below uses MozWebSocket if (typeof MozWebSocket != "undefined"). I'm currently running Firefox 7 Beta, and it works just fine as well as in the other browser given in the article suggested by Cameron below. I believe that will work with your Chrome 14 as well.

Comment: Although Firefox might have a problem on close events. I don't know what it is yet, but automatically start guessing. They might not be processing close messages yet. That seems likely, because the browser app suggested by Cameron below would print out the "bye" message sent back by the server in response to a close message (try it with Chromium and you'll see). Firefox throws an undefined error instead.

Comment: BTW: You should be able to update your browsers to the newest by going to About Google Chrome and About Firefox. They'll update automatically when you do that.

Comment: Just noticed someone contacted the server via Firefox 7. The server threw a null-pointer exception when receiving a close message (I think). This seems to indicate that Firefox is not sending the close message properly. I'll try with Firefox 7 myself again and see if I can repeat the error.

Comment: Nope. Didn't happen when I tried it.

Comment: Auto-update depends on the OS you are using. In Linux I'm actually quite happy that Firefox doesn't silently recompile and `make install` itself.

Comment: Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets

Comment: Firefox 7 - it's no longer Beta.

Answer (score 2):

THE WEBSOCKET SERVER DEMONSTRATION CURRENTLY WORKS WITH FIREFOX 7 BETA AND CHROME DEV (it's at 16 now). NOT FIREFOX 6, WHICH USES AND OLDER VERSION OF THE WEBSOCKET DRAFT PROTOCOL. (Just thought I'd mention that because I'm seeing a lot of server hits from Firefox 6 - must be dissatisfying for those who try it.)

Here's the code from the demonstration suggested by Cameron. Not sure if it fits your request for something "simple" exactly. It runs within a frame and the function showResults() that prints sends from the browser and what's received back from the server are sent to another frame. All the source code is available at ([demo server changes - check bottom of this blog article for up-to-date link to demo ... demo has a download link](http://highlevellogic.blogspot.se/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html)). Otherwise, it shouldn't take a huge amount of fiddling to turn this back (as it started) into a single page app. Suggest if you want that, start by pointing showResults() to a div in the same page instead of the other page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
 <title>HLL Command Center</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="description"  content="HTML5 Websockets for the HLL high level logic open source project" />
 <meta name="keywords"     content="high level logic, hll, open source, artificial intelligence, agents" />
 <meta name="author"       content="Roger F. Gay" />
 <meta name="owner"        content="rogerfgay@isr.nu" />
 <meta name="copyright"    content="%a9 2011 Roger F. Gay" />
 <meta name="license"      content="Lesser General Public License (LGPL v. 2.1)" />
 <meta name="website"      content="http://hll.dev.java.net" />
 <meta name="permission"   content="restricted" />
 <meta name="created"      content="20110801" />
 <meta name="changed"      content="20110902" />
 <meta name="security"     content="public" />
 <meta name="generator"    content="skill, knowledge, and intelligence" />

<style type="text/css">
 body {background-color:Khaki;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">



var websocket;
var connected=false;
var frameDoc;
var appType;

function doConnect(wsURIValue) {
  if (connected) {
    showResults("<span style='color: red;'>You're already connected!</span>");
  } else {
   if (appType == "Mozilla") {
     websocket = new MozWebSocket(document.getElementById('wsURI').value);
   } else {
     websocket = new WebSocket(document.getElementById('wsURI').value);

   }
   websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };

   websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };

   websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };

   websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }
}

function onOpen(evt) {
  connected=true;

  showResults("CONNECTED");

  doSend("WebSocket rocks!");

}

function onClose(evt) {
  connected=false;
  websocket.close();

  showResults("DISCONNECTED");
}
function doPing () {
  if (connected) {
   showResults("Not yet implemented in browser. Sending pseudo-ping message: 'Ping'.");
   websocket.send('Ping');
  } else {
    showResults("<span style='color: red;'>NOT CONNECTED: No pseudo-ping message sent.</span>");
  }
}

function onMessage(evt) {

  showResults("<span style='color: blue;'>RESP: " + evt.data + "</span>");

}

function onError(evt) {

  showResults("<span style='color: red;'>ERROR:</span> " + evt.data);

}

function doSend(message) {
  if (connected) {

    websocket.send(message);
    showResults("SENT: " + message);
  } else {
    showResults("<span style='color: red;'>NOT CONNECTED: No message sent.</span>");
  }
}
function doMultiple (message) {
 for (i=0; i<n_times; i++) {
  if (connected) {

    websocket.send(message);
    showResults("SENT: " + message);
  } else {
    showResults("<span style='color: red;'>NOT CONNECTED: No message sent.</span>");
  }
 }
}
function doClose(message) {
  if (connected) {

   showResults("CLOSING"); 

   websocket.close();
   connected=false;
  } else {
    showResults("<span style='color: red;'>NOT CONNECTED</span>");
  }

}

function showResults(message) {
  frameDoc.showResults(message);
}
function init() {
  if ((frameDoc = parent.results)) {
    document.getElementById('wsURI').value=wsUri;
    document.getElementById('message').value=mess;
    showResults("Frame communication confirmed.");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("testit1").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Interframe communication failed for this webpage.</span>";
    alert("Problem printing output: This application has been tested with up-to-date versions of Chrome, Firefox, and MSIE. (May 22, 2011)");
    return;
  }
  if (typeof MozWebSocket != "undefined") { // (window.MozWebSocket)
    appType = "Mozilla";
  } else if (window.WebSocket) {
    appType = "Chrome";
  } else {
    showResults('<strong style="color: red;">ERROR: This browser does not support WebSockets.</strong>');
    return;
  }
}
function changeNTimes () {
 n_times = flowContainer.ntimes.options[document.flowContainer.ntimes.selectedIndex].value;
}
var wsUri = "ws://isr2.mine.nu/echo";
var mess = "HLL International: " + String.fromCharCode(196,197,214) + " " + String.fromCharCode(945,946,948) + " " + String.fromCharCode(20149,20150,20153) + " " + String.fromCharCode(1490,1513,1488,1458) + " " + String.fromCharCode(286,350,399);
var n_times=5;
// window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

  <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>

<b>Server: </b>
<input type='button' onclick="doConnect(document.getElementById('wsURI').value)" value='Open Connection' />  
<input type='button' onclick="doClose()" value='Close Connection' />  
<input type='button' onclick="doPing()" value='Ping' /><br> 
<input type='text' style="text-align:left;" size='65' id='wsURI' /><br><br>
<span style="background-color:#CCCCCC">
<b><input type="radio" id="encoding" value="text" disabled="true" checked /> text  
<input type="radio" id="encoding" value="binary" disabled="true" /> binary</b> 
(binary not yet browser supported) <br><br>
</span>
<b>Message: </b>
<input type='button' onclick="doSend(document.getElementById('message').value)" value='Send Message to Server' /><br>
<textarea cols="50" rows="3" maxlength='260' id="message" ></textarea><br><br>
<b>Continuation (will be sent if not null): </b><br>
<textarea cols="50" rows="3" maxlength='125' id="continued" ></textarea><br><br>
<form name="flowContainer">
<input type='button' onclick="doMultiple(document.getElementById('message').value)" value='MultiMessage' /><br> 
<select name="ntimes" onchange="changeNTimes()">
  <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
</form>

<div id='testit3' name='testit3' style='color:blue'></div><br><br>
<div id='testit1' name='testit1' style='color:green'></div>
  <script>
   // You may want to place these lines inside an onload handler
   CFInstall.check({
     mode: "overlay",
     destination: "http://www.waikiki.com"
   });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All the source code is now available at : isr.nu/ws/WSJavaScript.zip

Comment: I might also mention the fact that if anyone wants to modify the code so that it also runs in MSIE (right now, it loads the top frame only and then chokes), it would be quite nice to have. The server should work with MSIE if you accept the automatic download / install of Google Frames.

Comment: Thanks for the note about Firefox 6.

Comment: I guess you've been among those I've seen hitting the server with Firefox 6 requests in the last 24 hours. I've seen that and all kinds of other stuff as well. Only correct "version 8" gets a response, but I still get information on every attempt along with the info sent.

Comment: Thanks to this post, I finally made my chatroom web page to work with Firefox 7.01. Thank! +1 to question +1 to this response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's a working demo of the final call version of the websocket protocol: version 8 (hybi-8,9,10 ... 17). (demo server changes ... see blog article below for up-to-date link)

There's a blog article about it here:
http://highlevellogic.blogspot.com/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html

NOTE THAT IT USES FIREFOX 7 BETA (NOT 6, which supports and older version of the protocol) or Chrome dev-channel 14 or later.

(I guess we were all a bit sleepy. This is the direct, short answer to your question. Also, some of the demo dhtml code is listed above, along with a place to download it if you want.)

Comment: Firefox 7.01 and 8 Beta have a problem with foreign characters. It doesn't effect the browser experience, just results in an error thrown on the server. Nothing to worry about. It keeps on running. Also, Firefox doesn't process a message returned on close. That's nothing to worry about either. You'll just get an error reported in the browser. It won't stop functioning. If you run Chrome dev-channel 14 or better, you'll notice that it receives a "bye" message in place of the ERROR that Firefox displays.

Comment: Firefox 7 is no longer Beta. It's been released.